# Vue3 disable mouse scroll wheel on click.middl

Tags: vuejs3

I'm want to handle the `@click.middle` event on one div without triggering the display of the scrolling wheel:

[image: Screenshot]

I tried with "prevent" or "stop" but chrome always trigger the scroll weel on middle click.

Is there any way in Vue 3 js to disable or reset the mouse to the normal cursor ?

**Edit:**

I thought I succeed to cancel the event by using `@auxclick.prevent.stop` on the div, it's perfect, it even triggers the `@click` event correctly.
But it doesn't work anymore. So I dont know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is `@mousedown.middle.prevent`

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nepq4gom/1/)